# Magento 1: why some observer method call getEvent() and some don't?

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, magento-1

Something I noticed recently and I'm curious about it.

### Example 1: the use of `getEvent()`

In `Mage_Core_Model_Locale` in the `setLocale()` method, an event is dispatched:

```
Mage::dispatchEvent('core_locale_set_locale', array('locale'=>$this));
```

An observer for this event is `bindLocale()` from `Mage_Adminhtml_Model_Observer`

```
public function bindLocale($observer)
{
    if ($locale=$observer->getEvent()->getLocale()) {
        if ($choosedLocale = Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getLocale()) {
            $locale->setLocaleCode($choosedLocale);
        }
    }
    return $this;
}
```

So as you can see, **to retrieve the locale, we first call `getEvent()` on the observer.**

### Example 2: without `getEvent()`

In `Mage_Wishlist_Block_Customer_Wishlist_Item_Options` in the `__construct()` method, an event is dispatched:

```
Mage::dispatchEvent('product_option_renderer_init', array('block' => $this));
```

So we agree that the same syntax is used for example 1 and 2.

However, an observer for this second example is `initOptionRenderer()` from `Mage_Bundle_Model_Observer`

```
public function initOptionRenderer(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $block = $observer->getBlock();
    $block->addOptionsRenderCfg('bundle', 'bundle/catalog_product_configuration');
    return $this;
}
```

And as you can see, **to retrieve the block, we don't call `getEvent()` on the observer**

### Question

- Why is the `getEvent()` method called in example #1 ? Or why is `getEvent()` not called in example #2 ?
- What's the purpose of the `getEvent()` method ?
- Where should one use `getEvent()` and where shouldn't one use it ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It probably has historical reasons, reaching back beyond the 1.0 release.

The `Varien_Event` object is the logical place to contain parameters for a concrete event, but since Magento passes a `Varien_Observer` object to all observer methods, shortcut access the parameters made sense (and it has been there at least since 1.1).

I actually don't see any value in two different objects *as they are used today*.

But it obviously not was planned like that from the beginning. In the method [`Mage::addObserver()`](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/d409dff20e992e97546568974399c456958299f9/app/Mage.php#L425-L433), not only the event and observer names and static arguments from the `<args>` XML node are set, but also a callback:

```
$observer->setName($observerName)->addData($data)->setEventName($eventName)->setCallback($callback);
```

This way, the observers are able to dispatch themselves, with `$observer->dispatch($event)`. In that case, the observers would not have the event data on themselves and you would need you use `getEvent()` to access it. But the method is not used anywhere, so in practice it does not matter.

If you want to practice some software archaeology and dig more, you'll find more dead code that hints on original ideas that never made it into the final product, like the `Varien_Event_Observer_Collection`.

Comment: Thank you. Was going to mention about "historical" aspects. Seems like you did that for us :)

Answer (score 8):

One thing is clear.

Calling  `$observer->getEvent()->getSomething()` and `$observer->getSomething()` return the same thing.

Take a look at the [`Mage_Core_Model_App::dispatchEvent`](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php#L1290) method.

At one point you have [`$event = new Varien_Event($args);`](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php#L1315) where `$args` are the arguments passed to the `dispatchEvent` method.
And `Varien_Event` extends `Varien_Object` so you can magically access the elements in `$args` from the `Varien_Event` instance.

but there is also this line [`$observer->addData($args);`](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php#L1329) where `$args` are the same things as above.

`Varien_Event_Observer` also extends `Varien_Object` so this allows you to magically access elements in `$args` via the Observer object.

Conclusion:

The `$_data` member in the Observer class and Event class contain kind of the same things. The observer has in addition a few other fields. like `event`, `event_name`.

Let's say the `$args` look like this:

```
array(
   'some_arg' => 'someArg',
   'other_arg' => 'otherArg',
)
```

When dispatching the event, the `$_data` in the Event object would look like this:

```
array(
   'some_arg' => 'someArg',
   'other_arg' => 'otherArg',
   'name' => 'event name here'
)
```

and in the Observer class would looks like this:

```
array(
   'some_arg' => 'someArg',
   'other_arg' => 'otherArg',
   'event_name' => 'event name here',
   'event' => instance of Varien_event,
   'callback' => ..., 
   'name' => 'observer name here'
)
```

But I cannot answer to why this lack of consistency exists.
I can only speculate that the code was written by 2 different developers.
If it's worth something, I always use `$observer->getEvent()->getSomething()`.

[EDIT]

> Why is the getEvent() method called in example #1 ? Or why is getEvent() not called in example #2 ?

Lack of consistency

> What's the purpose of the getEvent() method ?

The `Varien_Event` object should be a wrapper object over the arguments passed to the observer

> Where should one use getEvent() and where shouldn't one use it ?
>   Use them as you like. You will get the same result all the time.

Comment: Got the explanation regarding lack of consistency, see my answer

Comment: I always perfer `$observer->getEvent()` to grab any data in observer. I know we can grab data from `$observer` directly. But I don't do that because I always feel, injection of object `Varien_Event` is very specific to hold event data. Hence I always depend on event object. I feel that's the correct approach.

Comment: @RajeevKTomy see my answer, there's actually no point of using `getEvent()` except if you need the event name OR want to be Magento 1.0 compatible

Answer (score 3):

### Explanation regarding lack of consistency.

According to Vinai and what Vitaly Korotun told him at some point:

> **`getEvent()` is legacy.** Back **in Magento 1.0** days **the event data could
>   not be pulled from the observer directly.**

So if you don't need to get `event_name` and don't care too much about your code being Magento 1.0 compatible, you can leave out `getEvent()`.